# Parent Page becomes ‘frozen’ in Safari after commandLink with target=“_blank” is pressed in JSF 1.2 mojara

Tags: jsf, safari

On my webpage when i press command link its opening a new page perfectly on IE7/Firefox 3/Chrome/Safari 4.0.4 but after this none of the parent page's command buttons are not working ,this happens only in safari.I am using JSF 1.2 mojara.

Following is the my command link code:

```
<h:commandLink onclick="submitPrint('selectedAttributes',criteriaGrid,clauseGrid)" action="#{reportBacking.print}" target="_blank"></h:commandLink>
```

I have seen several fourms regarding this problem but they are suggesting the use of new mojara version which solves the some famous javascript problem document.forms Vs document.getElementByID().but my final javascript is fine (its using document.getElementById thing).

Comment: I indeed recall this, I even participated the discussion and recommended the OP to report the bug: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5260557 But your problem is probably different. Does it work if you remove `target="_blank"`? Which JSF 1.2 build exactly are you using? The latest, 1.2_14? https://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net/ Did you bother to report at their issuetracker? https://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net/issues/ The Mojarra guys are fast and prioritize browserspecific issues very high :)

Comment: i have tried without target="_blank" but then my parent page is redirected to new page and then i have lost my all command buttons,I have to open new link in new window or new tab.i am using 1.2_11 but i this tried with the latest binary 1.2_14 also... I hv raised a ticket on issue tracker...lets hope 4 d best :)